# Hibernate 5.3.10 one-to-many insertable = false behaves differently from Hibernate 5.2.1

Tags: java, database, hibernate, entitymanager, persist

I have two classes one contained within the other. SchoolClass and Student
When persisting them in Hibernate 5.2.1 everything works as expected, but when persisting in Hibernate 5.3.10 I have to remove or set `insertable = true`to get the same result otherwise I get exception.

What I'm looking for is a confirmation that the behavior of hibernate has changed. When where and why...

I have not been able to find any documentation about this at all.

```
jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - NULL not allowed for column "schoolClassId"; SQL statement:
insert into tStudent (studentId, name) values (null, ?)
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement.
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tSchoolClass")
@AutowiringTarget
public class SchoolClass {

   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "schoolClassId")
    private Long id;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "schoolClassId", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private List<Student> students;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tStudents")
@AutowiringTarget
public class Students {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "StudentId")
    private Long id;
```

H2 database.

```
CREATE TABLE tSchoolClass (
    schoolClassId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_tSchoolClass PRIMARY KEY (schoolClassnId));

CREATE TABLE tStudents (
    studentId  int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    schoolClassint NOT NULL,
    

    CONSTRAINT PK_tStudents PRIMARY KEY (studentId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_tStudent_tSchoolClass FOREIGN KEY (schoolClassId) REFERENCES tSchoolCLass (SchoolClassId));
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception `NULL not allowed for column "schoolClassId"` is clearly saying `schoolClassId` cannot be null.

Its the `nullable = false` property, that would enforce the not null constraint on the column schoolClassId which can be translated to `schoolClassId bigint NOT NULL` in the student create table.

The `insertable=true` on  `schoolClassId`  column would mean the column is included in the insert query. So whenever an instance of SchoolClass is persisted, the associated Student instances will be persisted too. The student entity insert will include the SchoolClassId column , its value referencing to SchoolClass id's instance, which is not null in this case.

So in short, anytime the column schoolClassId is null, the constraint violation will be thrown, so keeping insertable=false, you would need to set nullable = true if you have to get rid of the violation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not really what I'm looking for. This has worked for years and now it is not since I updated to 5.3.10 the important part of the question is why where and when this changed.

Comment: My guess is it started working as expected since 5.3.10 as if nullable=false, the insert shud fail with the violation. If it didnt happen previous to 5.3.10 it is due to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13241

Comment: Thank you!
This really was a great help! Did not feel comfortable leaving it up to only my own testing wanted to have some verification from other sources! :)